# how to parse nested json in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

I have below json
// here except stars am populating value on list view
// and stars am displaying in drop down after v click , but am not able to parse that value
// Please help

```
"entries": [
  {
"Doctor_Criteria_2": "Physician",
"Status": "Completed",
"Comment": "Testing",
"Timeline_For_Reporting": "1 month",
"Doctor_Criteria_1": "10",
"Speciality": "1",
"Faculty_No": "2",
"stars": [
  "Sumit",
  "Kumar",
  "Saini"
],
"Event_Id": "1503209071",
"Speaker_No": "2",
"End_Date_Time": "2017-08-25T10:00",
"Budget_Allocation": "2017-08-26T10:00",
"No_Of_Doctors_Assign": "Barbiturates",
"Doctor_Assignment": "Physician",
"Actual_Budget": "15000",
"Start_Date_Time": "Enthuse",
"Event_Name": "Med_Vision",
"Product_List": "10000",
"Assign_Team_Name": "0",
"Modular_No": "3"
},
```

// below code am using to parse the json and displaying it on listview

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){      
//    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
//        mode = 'search/movie?query=',
//        movieName = '&query='+encodeURI('Batman'),        
//        key = '&api_key=5fbddf6b517048e25bc3ac1bbeafb919';    
    var url = 'https://usv.mybluemix.net/USV/Json.jsp';

    $.ajax({
//        url: url + mode + key + movieName ,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
             $('#work-in-progress').fadeOut(0);
            ajax.parseJSON(result);


        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');

            document.getElementById("internet_access").innerHTML="No internet access";
        }
    });         
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#Doctor_Name').empty();
    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.Event_Creation_Id == movieInfo.id) {
   // here i want to display stars value in drop down in Doctor_Name
            $('#Doctor_Name').append(' <option value="'+row.stars+'">'+row.stars+'</option>');
             document.getElementById("user").value =USER_NAME;

         // document.getElementById("Store_name").value = row.Event_Name;

          //  $("#Doctor_Name").select2("val", "");
            $('#Doctor_Name').selectmenu('refresh');       
        }
    });    
});

$(document).on('vclick', '#movie-list li a', function(){  
    movieInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
});

var movieInfo = {
    id : null,
    result : null
}

var ajax = {  
    parseJSON:function(result){  
        movieInfo.result = result.entries;
        $.each(result.entries, function(i, row) {

            if (row.Status != "Completed") {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="'  + row.Event_Creation_Id + '">' +'<h3>' + row.Event_Name + '</h3><p1>' + row.Event_Creation_Id + '</p1><br><p2>' + row.Start_Date_Time +'</p2><p2>'+row.End_Date_Time + '</p2><p>'+row.Status +'</p></a></li>');
        }});
        $('#movie-list').listview('refresh').trigger("create");;
    }
}
```

// Please ignore English mistakes as am learning .
Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: data is not coming in drop down

Comment: Please have a look on json and code you'll understand , actually am not getting how to parse that nested json

Comment: can you post the html for the listview and check whether you are getting value at `movieInfo.id` inside `pagebeforeshow` handler.

Comment: sir, I am able to parse all value on listview , but in entries there is one more array stars ,i want to  display the value which is inside of stars in second page drop down

Comment: i tried 
$.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
$.each(row.stars, function(k, data) {

Comment: updated my code

Comment: <select type="text" name="ticket_id_set" id="Doctor_Name" data-iconpos="left" class="inline" data-theme="a">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Doctor</option>
              
          </select>

Comment: https://usv.mybluemix.net/USV/Json.jsp 
this is my json please chek the formate if you have time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will not work

```
 $('#Doctor_Name').append(' <option value="'+row.stars+'">'+row.stars+'</option>');
```

Because `row.stars` is an array , so you need to use another for loop or $.each to loop through the values of array `row.stars` to append to dropdown

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#Doctor_Name').empty();

    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.Event_Creation_Id == movieInfo.id) {
   // here i want to display stars value in drop down in Doctor_Name
          if(row.stars && row.stars.length > 0)
          {

            for(var i =0;i<row.stars.length;i++)
              {
                 $('#Doctor_Name').append(' <option value="'+row.stars[i]+'">'+row.stars[i]+'</option>');
              }

        }
        document.getElementById("user").value =USER_NAME;

         // document.getElementById("Store_name").value = row.Event_Name;

          //  $("#Doctor_Name").select2("val", "");
            $('#Doctor_Name').selectmenu('refresh');       
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: then what should i write to get value in drop dron in Doctor_Name

Comment: <select type="text" name="ticket_id_set" id="Doctor_Name" data-iconpos="left" class="inline" data-theme="a">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Doctor</option>
              
          </select>

Comment: above is the html code.. data is not coming in drop down sir

Comment: https://usv.mybluemix.net/USV/Json.jsp 
this is my json please chek the formate if you have time

Comment: sir data is coming

Comment: but sir all three value is coming in same row, not drop down

Comment: @Gaurav `"stars": [
  "Sumit",
  "Kumar",
  "Saini"
]` it refers to a single person or 3 diffrent person?

Comment: all are three value that i wanted to show in drop down
sumit
kumar
saini
 in this formate

Comment: its just hardcode value.. am learning  so.. am trying to parse and display in drop down

Comment: @Gaurav what value are you getting in dropdown now?

Comment: sumit kumar saini 
all in same row

Comment: and what if i have to display that star in listview

$('#movie-data').append('<li data-identifier="'+row.stars[i]+'" data-store-name="'+row.stars[i]+'"><input type="checkbox"/>'+row.stars[i]+'</li>');

Answer (score 0):

Modify parseJSON like this to see the `stars`

```
parseJSON: function(result) {
  movieInfo.result = result.entries;
  $.each(result.entries, function(i, row) {
    if (row.stars && row.stars.length) {
      row.stars.forEach(function(s) {
         $('#Doctor_Name').append($('<option value="'+s+'">'+s+'</option>'));
      });
    }
    if (row.Status != "Completed") {
      $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.Event_Creation_Id + '">' + '<h3>' + row.Event_Name + '</h3><p1>' + row.Event_Creation_Id + '</p1><br><p2>' + row.Start_Date_Time + '</p2><p2>' + row.End_Date_Time + '</p2><p>' + row.Status + '</p></a></li>');
    }
  });
  $('#movie-list').listview('refresh').trigger("create");;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks 
So by using this can i display stars value in Doctor_Name (drop down)

Comment: sorry sir am not getting value in #Doctor_Name drop down.
do i need to change more in js .

Comment: that doctor name am getting in scond page after selecting the list